# In a named transclude slot, how do I transclude *only* the element's contents?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I've got a basic directive that I want to use transclusion. The relevant options are set up as follows:

```
restrict: "E",
replace: true,
transclude: {
  'toolbar': 'toolbarSlot'
},
scope: {
  pageTitle: "@"
},
templateUrl: "path/to/my/template.html"
```

My template is:

```
<header class="page-header">
  <h1 class="page-title heading">{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
  <div class="page-header-toolbar toolbar" ng-transclude="toolbar">
    <!-- "toolbar" transcluded content should go here -->
  </div>
</header>
```

And finally, when I use the directive, I'm using it this way:

```
<my-custom-page-header-directive page-title="Title">
  <toolbar-slot>
    <button>Button</button>
    <button>Another button</button>
  </toolbar-slot>
</my-custom-page-header-directive>
```

The problem is, in the DOM it ends up as something like this, with an extraneous `toolbar-slot` element mixed into the transcluded content:

```
<header class="page-header">
  <h1 class="page-title heading">Title</h1>
  <div class="page-header-toolbar toolbar">
    <toolbar-slot>
      <button>Button</button>
      <button>Another button</button>
    </toolbar-slot>
  </div>
</header>
```

**Is there a way (using `ngTransclude`) to only transclude the *contents* of the slot element?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the answer is **no, there isn't a way to do that as of right now**.

[An open issue on the Angular.js repository](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14244) shows that there are misgivings about implementing the ability to use `ngTransclude` that way:

> I'm not a fan of adding a replace functionality to the slot transclusion. It would introduced the same problems we have with normal "replace" and transclude: element.

But, apparently, you ["can actually do this manually if your really need it"](http://plnkr.co/edit/vBEmbo65jB3Jug2L4Ynj?p=preview).